# Why does `TakesExam.grade NOT IN ("b", "f", "u")` exclude rows with `grade = 0` in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Why does `TakesExam.grade NOT IN ("b", "f", "u")` exclude rows with `grade = 0` in mysql?

How do I fix the above problem? Every row with a grade equal to 0 or NULL gets excluded from the result?

Comment: This may have to do with varying data types.  What type is `TakesExam.grade`?  It *may* be converting `'b'`, `'f'` and `'u'` to *ints* to compare it to `0`.

Comment: [Can I configure MySQL's typecasting to consider 0 != 'foo'?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36078/3690)

Comment: If it's an `INT`, then what do you expect `NOT IN ("b", "f", "u")` to return?  When you do `0 NOT IN ("b", "f", "u")`, it *converts* the letters to ints which  makes them all 0.

Comment: Do CAST(grade AS CHAR) convert grade to a string and not just a char ?

Comment: `CAST(grade AS CHAR) NOT IN ("b", "f", "u")` should work, yes.